# iCloudKit lifecycle for databases

Tags: ios, icloud

I have created an app, that logs records to the private iCloud database, records that you can edit and delete with it. An App I would hope to upload to the apps store in due course.

But a question remains in the back of my mind. If somebody deletes said app, what happens to the iCloudKit database and records within it that it has created. Does private database get deleted when you delete the app or does said database simple "hang" around ... with no owner ? effectively taking up/waisting valuable disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudKit database stays in place. If the user reinstalls your app on the same device or another device, the data will show up (assuming your app properly handles the existing data in iCloud).

Apple provides no mechanism for a user to clean up any unused iCloud databases. So if a user uses your app and uses up a bunch of storage in iCloud, and then later simply deletes your app and never uses it again, that space is being wasted with no way to clean it up.